# Error Database Magento 2.3 migration from localhost to server

Tags: magento2

I have migrated all the files from my local server to my production server, I have copied the database, I have changed the database connection data in the file /app/etc/env.php with the new URL and I have cleaned cache. In the error shown below, you can see in bold that you are using the password of the database user that you had in the local environment, but I have changed it in the configuration file. How can this be?

**env.php**

```
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            'dbname' => 'magentodb',
            'username' => 'magentoUser',
            'password' => 'Password.19#test$/',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

**Error**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'magentoUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'magentoUser', '**Password2019**',
>   Array) #1
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(406):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #4
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_w...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(541):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`store_w...', Array) #6
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(615):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `store_w...',
>   Array) #7
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #8
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(87):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
>
> ## 9 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(57):
>
> Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->getEntities('store_website',
>   'code') #10
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #11
>   /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('') #12
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Type/Scopes.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get() #13
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Type\Scopes->get('stores/1') #14
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php(106):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('scopes', 'stores/1', Array) #15
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php(127):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('1') #16
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(181):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getActiveStoreById('1') #17
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById('1') #18
>   /var/www/magento/app/code/Rokanthemes/RokanBase/Model/Rewrite/Store/StoreManager.php(12):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #19
>   /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
>   Rokanthemes\RokanBase\Model\Rewrite\Store\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)
>
> ## 20 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
>
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #21
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
>   Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #22
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
>   NULL) #23
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>
> ## 24 /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #25
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #26
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'SQLSTATE[HY000]...', Array) #27
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
>   Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'SQLSTATE[HY000]...',
>   Array) #28
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Monolog\Logger->error('SQLSTATE[HY000]...') #29
>   /var/www/magento/pub/index.php(37):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 30 {main} Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magentoUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(406):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_w...', Array) #4
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(541):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`store_w...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(615):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `store_w...',
>   Array) #6
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #7
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(87):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
>
> ## 8 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(57):
>
> Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->getEntities('store_website',
>   'code') #9
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #10
>   /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('') #11
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Type/Scopes.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get() #12
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Type\Scopes->get('stores/1') #13
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php(106):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('scopes', 'stores/1', Array) #14
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php(127):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('1') #15
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(181):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getActiveStoreById('1') #16
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById('1') #17
>   /var/www/magento/app/code/Rokanthemes/RokanBase/Model/Rewrite/Store/StoreManager.php(12):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #18
>   /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
>   Rokanthemes\RokanBase\Model\Rewrite\Store\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)
>
> ## 19 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
>
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #20
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
>   Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #21
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
>   NULL) #22
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>
> ## 23 /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #24
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #25
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'SQLSTATE[HY000]...', Array) #26
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
>   Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'SQLSTATE[HY000]...',
>   Array) #27
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Monolog\Logger->error('SQLSTATE[HY000]...') #28
>   /var/www/magento/pub/index.php(37):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 29 {main}

Comment: Try using an IP for your host instead of localhost

Comment: do you say here?     'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' =>

Comment: I have the same error :-(

Comment: yeah , try to change it

Comment: how about in core_config_data table, have you changed the base_url and base_secure_url?

Comment: yes, I put my IP but I have the same error (I have cleaned the cache even)

Comment: can you try renaming your env file to env.php.bk , then run your website setup wizard check if it will work

Comment: Yes, I have copied all the files to FTP, I have imported the database, I have changed the IP in that table and the env.php file, but it still does not work

Comment: If I do the assistant, will it delete my database?

Comment: can you post your env database configuration

Comment: The problem is that in the error screen you see a password for my database user that is not the one I have in the env.php file (you can see the configuration above in the post)

Comment: make a backup of your database and try the one I recommend, the one with renaming your env.php file

Comment: and running wizard again

Comment: Ok and then what is the next step?

Comment: try to check with new database from live then after finish dump your database to the working live database

Comment: All right! I did what you told me, and when setting up the new database it worked and the data I had was maintained, so I do not have to do anything else, no?

Comment: Yeah. nothing as long as everything is already there.

Comment: and it works well and fine

Comment: Yes is working fine! but I did not dump my database again so, is good? Or do I have to dump the database again?

Comment: if there are missing products data or customer information or orders try to dump your database from local but if not, it's fine no need to dump :)